# IE11 cannot display table using D3?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

I am using the following a table

```
var table = svg.append("foreignObject")
.attr("y",0)
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "50%")
.append("xhtml:body")

table.append("table")

table.append('thead').append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')

  .data(scope.columns).enter()
  .append('th')
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.cl;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.head;
  });

// append body rows
table.append('tbody')
  .selectAll('tr')
  .data(scope.movies).enter()
  .append('tr')
  .selectAll('td')
  .data(function(row, i) {
    // evaluate column objects against the current row
    return scope.columns.map(function(c) {
      var cell = {};
      d3.keys(c).forEach(function(k) {
        cell[k] = typeof c[k] == 'function' ? c[k](row, i) : c[k];
      });
      return cell;
    });
  }).enter()
  .append('td')
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.html;
  })
  .attr('class', function(d) {
    return d.cl;
  });
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and firefox. In IE11  cannot display the table

Included fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewarnier/fzssLmmf/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `foreignObject` doesn't work on IE. Look at the bottom of the MDN page, in the section "Browser compatibility": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: Have other method can archive it ?

Comment: For IE? No. You cannot append HTML elements to an SVG without foreignObject.

Comment: Although OPs can (and should) edit their question once it was closed (like clarifying a question that was closed for being "unclear"), you're making *a different question* in your edit. Don't do that: It makes no sense, it makes my close vote seem incorrect and it will take 5 votes to reopen it. It's way easier simply posting **another question**, asking how to do what you want to do without using `foreignObject`.